# Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't detect logitech pebble mouse

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

When I was trying Ubuntu on a pen drive I was able to pair my mouse without problems. But now that I installed the OS it doesn't detect it anymore. I'm able to pair with my phone and send/receive files no problems.